# how to get DNS Info in android

Tags: android, dns, dhcp, android-networking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you get the current DNS servers for Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3070144/how-do-you-get-the-current-dns-servers-for-android)

I want to get hold of the dns servers in android. [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249916/how-do-i-find-the-dns-servers-in-android-from-a-java-program) says there is some android.net.NetworkUtils class but I found out that there's no such class. Same question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3070144/how-do-you-get-the-current-dns-servers-for-android) but it was unresolved.

Comment: So, do you want information about DHCP or DNS? Those are completely different things.

Comment: @svick I want info about dns. but not for wifi interface, rather for gprs/3g interface.

Comment: @prongs can clarify how marked answer helps you to get DNS servers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a Project example that works:

https://github.com/rorist/android-network-discovery/blob/master/src/info/lamatricexiste/network/DnsDiscovery.java

```
for (long i = start; i < end + 1; i++) {
    hosts_done++;
    HostBean host = new HostBean();
    host.ipAddress = NetInfo.getIpFromLongUnsigned(i);
    try {
        InetAddress ia = InetAddress.getByName(host.ipAddress);
        host.hostname = ia.getCanonicalHostName();
        host.isAlive = ia.isReachable(timeout) ? 1 : 0;
    } catch (java.net.UnknownHostException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
    }
    if (host.hostname != null && !host.hostname.equals(host.ipAddress)) {
        // Is gateway ?
        if (discover.net.gatewayIp.equals(host.ipAddress)) {
            host.deviceType = 1;
        }
        // Mac Addr
        host.hardwareAddress = HardwareAddress.getHardwareAddress(host.ipAddress);
        // NIC vendor
        try {
            host.nicVendor = HardwareAddress.getNicVendor(host.hardwareAddress);
        } catch (SQLiteDatabaseCorruptException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
        publishProgress(host);
    } else {
        publishProgress((HostBean) null);
```

Comment: well, Actually I want to get dns addresses but many threads mentioned I have to get an object of DhcpInfo class that's what I meant by getting dhcp info.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this looks like a good answer:

[How do you get the current DNS servers for Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3070144/how-do-you-get-the-current-dns-servers-for-android)

> `android.net.ConnectivityManager` will deliver you an array of
>   NetworkInfo's using `getAllNetworkInfo()`. Then use
>   `android.net.NetworkUtils.runDhcp()` to get a DhcpInfo for any given
>   network interface - the `DhcpInfo structure` has the IP address for `dns1`
>   and `dns2` for that interface (which are integer values representing the
>   IP address).

Here is another good link:

http://www.devdaily.com/java/jwarehouse/android/wifi/java/android/net/wifi/WifiStateTracker.java.shtml

Comment: did you read the question carefully? I said there is nothing like android.net.NetworkUtils I don't know why